# "preg_replace()" not working properly.

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I've a text file that I extracted all the domain addresses strting with `http://`
now I want to replace all the `http://`. in my matches array with "" but nothing is happening im not even getting an an error

```
$list = file_get_contents( 'file.txt' );
preg_match_all( "/http:\/\/.([a-z]{1,24}).([a-z^0-9-]{1,23}).([a-z]{1,3})/", $list, $matches );

for ($i=0; $i>=50; $i++) {
    $pattern = array();
    $replacement = array();
    $pattern[0][$i] = "/http:\/\/.[w-w]{1,3}/";
    $replacement[0][$i] = '';

    preg_replace( $pattern[0][$i], $replacement[0][$i], $matches[0][$i] );
}

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Can you show us your input "file.txt"?

Comment: Are you sure your loop condition is correct? This loop is never executed

Comment: `for($i=0;$i>=50;$i++){` is a non-op.

Comment: Perhaps it should be `for ($i=0; $i<=50; $i++)` ???

Comment: **1.** Your loop condition is incorrect. **2.** Your regex for matching domain names is incorrect. You need to escape the dot meta-character inside the regex. Try this instead: `~http://([a-z]{1,24})\.([a-z^0-9-]{1,23})\.([a-z]{1,3})~`. **3.** `preg_replace()` doesn't return the matches. You need to store it in a variable, like so: `$ret = preg_replace(...);` or `echo` it: `echo preg_replace(...);`.

Comment: tried both <= and >= i always forget the difference. the text file is a list of links repeated yellow book pages random urls single lines not formatted like the preg_match_all regex extracts. the print_r($matches) shows the array how its supposed to be but the preg_replace is not removing the http://www. before the earlier extracted URLS

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never runs because `0 >= 50` yields `false`. That said, what you're looking for is a map operation:

```
$matches = array_map(function($match) {
    return preg_replace('~^http://w{1,3}~', '', $match);
}, $matches[0]);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks alot  kind sir ;) that did the trick. the loop I always try both <=|>= because i forget what eats what every time

Comment: @user3434985: Your regex for matching domain names is also incorrect. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126647/why-isnt-preg-replace-replacing-the-string#comment35357186_23126647) under the question.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all`  has also problem. The period in regular expression matches any character.

```
$list = file_get_contents( 'file.txt' );
preg_match_all( "/http:\/\/([a-z]{1,24})\.([a-z^0-9-]{1,23})\.([a-z]{1,3})/", $list, $matches );

$pattern = "/http:\/\/(.[w-w]{1,3})/";
$replacement = '$1';
$matches[0] = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $matches[0] );

print_r($matches);
```